# Pip cannot install packages after upgrading to Catalina

Tags: catalina, homebrew, python

I haven't used pipenv since upgrading, but today I needed to work on an old project and I'm getting problems with pipenv and other python utilities. I did a `xcode-select --install` and `brew update && brew upgrade` and that didn't help. I ever tried `brew bundle dump --describe --global && brew bundle install --global`. Even a simple commmand like `pip3 install sorteddict` fails with

```
  Using cached sorteddict-1.2.1.tar.gz (5.2 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/_2/qxtp7dds6r5df9q369cxlswm0000gn/T/pip-install-00izrc3z/sorteddict/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/_2/qxtp7dds6r5df9q369cxlswm0000gn/T/pip-install-00izrc3z/sorteddict/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/_2/qxtp7dds6r5df9q369cxlswm0000gn/T/pip-install-00izrc3z/sorteddict/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/_2/qxtp7dds6r5df9q369cxlswm0000gn/T/pip-install-00izrc3z/sorteddict/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/_2/qxtp7dds6r5df9q369cxlswm0000gn/T/pip-install-00izrc3z/sorteddict/setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: have you tried `brew reinstall python` or reinstalling any other tool that's causing errors ?

Comment: @ankii didn't help.

Comment: can you check which file/ folder is actually missing in '/private/var/folders/_2/qxtp7dds6r5df9q369cxlswm0000gn/T/pip-install-00izrc3z/sorteddict/setup.py' ?

Comment: @ankii Everything up to and including `T` is present. There are a shitload of `pip-req-tracker-*` directories in that directory, but no `pip-install-*` directories.

Comment: It seems pip still thinks that there's a setup file lying around. Let me see if there's a cache clearing command. You can check `pip --help` though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9510610 there

Comment: Deleted ~/Library/Caches/pip*, did a `pipenv lock --clear` and it died, did a `pip3 install --no-cache-dir sorteddict` and it died with the same error as before.

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder if it's just a problem with `sorteddict`. I was able to `pip3 install lxml` just fine. I tried `pip3 install sorteddict` on my linux box and got a similar error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a problem with SortedDict. I can `pip install` other packages. I commented sorteddict and sortedcollection out of my Pipfile and I can start up my pipenv. (I was only manually installing sorteddict because pipenv wasn't working.)